Notation conventions and notations related questions relating to the denfinition for extension and contraction of an ideal.
The definitions below are taken from the following sources;
Certain Number-Theoretic Episodes in Algebra, First Edition by R. Sivaramakrishnan
A SINGULAR Introduction to Commutative Algebra, Second Edition by Greuel and Pfister
Algebra Vol 2: Rings by Luthar and Passi
Background

Definition 1:  Let $A$ be a subring of the commutative ring $A'$.  If $\mathfrak{a}$ is an ideal of $A'$, then the ideal of $\mathfrak{a}'\cap A$ of $A$ is called the contraction of $\mathfrak{a}'$ (to $A$).  If $\mathfrak{a}$ is an ideal of $A$, the ideal $\mathfrak{a}A'$ of $A'$ generated by $\mathfrak{a}$ is called the extension (to $A'$) of $\mathfrak{a}$.
More generally, let $\rho; A\to A'$ be a homomorphism of commutative rings.  If $\mathfrak{a}'$ is an ideal of $A'$, then $\rho^{-1}(\mathfrak{a}')$ is an ideal of $A$.  This ideal of $A$ is called the contraction of $\mathfrak{a}'$ (w.r.t $\rho$), and is denoted by $\mathfrak{a}^{'c}$, or by abuse of notation $\mathfrak{a}'\cap A$.  If $\mathfrak{a}$ is an ideal of $A$, then the ideal $\rho(\mathfrak{a})A'$ of $A'$ generated by $\rho(\mathfrak{a})$ is called the extension of $\mathfrak{a}$ (w.r.t $\rho$).  The extension of $\mathfrak{a}$ is denoted by $\mathfrak{a}^e$, or by abuse of notation, by $\mathfrak{a}A'$.  An ideal of $A$ (resp:  $A'$) is called a contracted ideal of $A$ (resp; an extended ideal of $A'$) if it is the contraction (resp: extension) of an ideal of $A'$ (resp: $A$).

Definition 2:  For a ring map $\rho:A\to A'$ an ideal $\mathfrak{a}\subset A'$ the ideal $\rho^{-1}(\mathfrak{a})\subset A$ is called the contraction of $\mathfrak{a}$; for $A\subset A'$ the contraction of $\mathfrak{a}$ is $\mathfrak{a}\cap A$.
Definition 3:  Let $\rho:A\to A'$ be a ring homomorphism.  Suppose that $\mathfrak{a}$ denote an ideal of $A$.  The extenstion $\mathfrak{a}^e$ of $\mathfrak{a}$ via $\rho$ is defined as ideal $\rho(\mathfrak{a})A'$ which is generated by $\rho(\mathfrak{a})$ in $A'$
To be precise, $\mathfrak{a}^e$ is given by the set
$$\{\sum_\text{finite} \rho(a_i)b_i:a_i\in \mathfrak{a}, b_i\in A'\}.$$
Questions
I have some questions about notation conventions for contraction and extension of an ideal $\mathfrak{a}$.
1) When speaking of extension/contraction of ideals, is it usually or must it be in the context with respect to two different rings $A, A'$.
2) If it is in reference to two different rings, then there will be a ring homomomorphism say $\rho$ mapping from one to the other like from $A$ to $A'$.  In the case of contraction of an ideal, if it is the case that $A\subset A'$, then the map $\rho$ would be an injective homomorphism (embedding).  Would the map $\rho$ always have to be an identity map?
3)  Can the following case be possible? We have $A\neq A', A\cap A'\neq \emptyset$, a homomorphic map $\rho: A\to A'$ and an ideal $\mathfrak{a}'\subset A'$ with $\rho^{-1}(\mathfrak{a}')\subset A\cap A'$, then is the ideal $\rho^{-1}(\mathfrak{a}')$ still consider as a contraction of $\mathfrak{a}'$, and since we don't have $A\subset A'$, then the hommorphism from $A$ to $A'$ won't be an embedding.  In such case it would not make sense to use the contraction notation $\rho^{-1}(\mathfrak{a}')\cap A$?
4)  I notice that for extension of an ideal, there seems to be a few different ways to denote it, $\mathfrak{a}^e=(\rho(\mathfrak{a}))=\mathfrak{a}A'=\{\sum_\text{finite} \rho(a_i)b_i:a_i\in \mathfrak{a}, b_i\in A'\}$.  So when referring to the extension of an ideal of $A'$, is it simply to use one of the following three notations: $\mathfrak{a}^e, (\rho(\mathfrak{a})), \mathfrak{a}A'$?
Thank you in advance.

Extension and contraction of an ideal is with respect to some ring homomorphism $\rho$. When context is clear, we don’t explicitly mention $\rho$. If $A\subseteq A’$, then we have obvious inclusion homomorphism. For question 4), answer is yes. You can also use $\rho (\mathfrak{a})A’$.

@user264745 if in the case of $A\subset A'$, is the inclusion homomorphism an injective map. Is the reason why it is also an identity map for the reason of figuring out how to compute the extension of the ideal?  Also I am not sure when terms like embedding or inclusion homomorphism are used, does that necessarily implicitly mean the map is an identity map. Lastly what about the case in 3) where we have $\rho^{-1}(\mathfrak{a}')\subset A\cap A'$, is the contraction notation still $\rho^{-1}(\mathfrak{a}')\cap A$?

Inclusion map is trivially injective. Recall if $A\subseteq A’$, then $A\hookrightarrow A’$ defined by $a\mapsto a$ is called inclusion map. It is technically not an identity map because domain $\neq$ codomain. Embedding, in present context, means injective. For more detail see. My first comment answer your question 3). By definition of contraction, $(\mathfrak{a}’)^c=\rho^{-1}(\mathfrak{a}’)$.

@user264745 If I am understanding you correctly, for Definition 2, $(\mathfrak{a}')^c=\rho^{-1}(\mathfrak{a})$ irrespective if $A\subset A'$ and that $\rho:a\mapsto a$ where $\rho:A\to A'$ is an embedding/inclusion homomorphism is not consider an identity map even though the expression written out is coincidentally identical? The reasons I am asking all these little details is in Definition 1, the author states about an abuse of notations, in the case of $\mathfrak{a}'\cap A$, but for Definition 2 when we have the case of $A\subset A'$, it doesn't look like an abuse of notation.

@user264745 thank you so much for answering all my questions.

This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Please notice that comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See How do comments work for more information. Therefore, I suggest to post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list. @user264745
